# How to use Context to access/manipulate another class/activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-context

I want to create a generic AsynceTask class that all my activities use/share for downloading content from a url. for this reason, I don't want the OnPostExecute to do anything other than to send the content back to some method in the activity that invoked the AsyncTask class.

I know that I need to create a constructor that sets the context of the Activity that invoked the `AsyncTask`, but then what, how do I use the context to send something back the the activity   corresponding to that context. I've seen no tutorials that show how to use context in this manner.

Lets say I have:

```
public class LoginActivity {

    public int ActivityMember;

    public void HandleButtonClick(void){
        DownloadFromURL task = new DownloadFromURL(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }

    public void HandleLoginResult(int x){
        ActivityMember = x;
    }
}
```

now in a separate java file I have:

```
    private class DownloadFromURL extends AsyncTask<List<NameValuePair>, Long, JSONObject> {
Context context;

    public void DownloadFromURL (Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
         context.(<- *my question involves this part of code)
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I cant call `context.ActivityMember`, or `context.HandleLoginResult(y)` inside `onPostExecute`, because context is not of the type `LoginActivity`, its a Context.
So how can I access members or methods belonging to `LoginActivity`, using it's context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `((ActivityName)contextName).methodName()`

But it is not a good solution. You can try something like [this](http://256design.com/blog/asynctask-in-android-and-oncompletelistener/)

Answer (score 1):

pass your activity name along with the context to the async class.

```
    protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject result)
    {

            if(classname.equals("LoginActivity"))
            {
                ((LoginActivity) object).method();
            }
                    else if(classname.equals("MainActivity"))
            {
                ((MainActivity) object).method();
            }


}
```

Comment: This is a BAD idea! Maintenance nightmare on the long run, not to mention how ugly cascaded ifs look.

Comment: what solution would you recommend?

Comment: Future-proofing your app would require something like my solution. If you really want something quick and dirty that trades in maintainability for coding speed, go with this.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do, you just create a method in your activity and call it from the instance you pass through AsyncTask parent class constructor.

Assume you have in your activity some like this:

```
public void Foo(ArrayList<DataType> data)
{
//Do some with data
}
```

You then call this method from onPostExecute like this:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<DataType> data)
        {
                activity.Foo(data);
        }
```

Where activity is the instance passed through the constructor.
Cheers

Comment: While this could work, it would require the AsyncTask to know exactly which class it's parent will be, making it a non-generic solution.

Comment: That's true, but for god's sake, is just casting it, I pointed out this solution for the sake of simplicity given that deducting what you are saying is pretty easy

Answer (score 0):

This involves basic Object Oriented Programming knowledge.

If you look closely at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html you can see Activity extends Context, that's why you can get away with passing `this` to your AsyncTask constructor and having the compiler do the required object slicings.

We can use that to your advantage: Create an abstract class extending Activity (Let's say: DataActivity, just an example though, name it whatever you want) and write a method named `onDataDownloadComplete(JSONObject json)` (A callback) on it, that you would of call on your AsyncTask's `onPostExecute`. Make all your activities extend from DataActivity and implement that method. Change the AsyncTask context from Context to DataActivity so you can call the `onDataDownloadComplete` callback and you are done. Again, as DataActivity would of extend Activity and Activity extends Context, DataActivity or anyhting extending it would be a valid context for the AsyncTask.

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

I realized there is another way to achieve what I was trying to do. This takes away the Asyncrony, but for the case of login, I actually do want the UI to be inactive while the app trys to log in.

After I call

```
asyncTask.execute()
```

I can call

```
asyncTask.get()
```

and that will retrieve the result of doInBackground and allow you to run it on the spot. Alternatively I can use a timeout so I dont block forever:

```
asynceTask.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```